# Filesystemwatcher doesn't trigger event

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I am trying to monitor a directory for new files in it with the `FileSystemWatcher` Class.

My Problem is that the event doesn't get triggered. My watcher class is:

```
public class Filewatcher
{
    private FileSystemWatcher watcher;

    public Filewatcher(string path, string filefilter)
    {
        this.watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        this.watcher.Path = path;
        this.watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName; //| NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.LastAccess
        this.watcher.Filter =  filefilter;
        this.watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
    }

    public void start_watching()
    {
        //this.watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
        this.watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to quit\r\n");
        Console.ReadLine(); 
    }

    private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        //FileInfo objFileInfo = new FileInfo(e.FullPath);
        //if (!objFileInfo.Exists) return;
        Console.WriteLine("got the change\r\n");
        global_functions.perform_action(Global_Vars.thereader.read(e.FullPath), Global_Vars.thepattern);
    }
}
```

Operating System is Win 7 Prof x64

Comment: what is the content of `filefilter` variable!Are you filtering for specific files..try `*.*` to enable raising events for any type of file

Comment: filefilter var is "*.eml"
path var is c:\afolder

Comment: i had a typo in my xml-config file everything works fine. sorry for opening that thread

Comment: We'll need a complete but simple example that reproduces the problem.  If I take your code and instantiate a Filewatcher object with `new Filewatcher(".", "*.*")` and call `start_watcher` on that instance then create file in the same directory as the exe, `OnChanged` is called

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't make a call to start_watching().  Add a call to that and it may work better.

Comment: Accept the answer that Peter made.  That will "Close" the thread.